# Jooq: only jooq's logo is logged

Tags: java, sql, logging, jooq

Problem: Jooq logs only it's logo ("thank you for using jooq"), but does not log the queries as per docs.

Jooq version: `3.10.2` (tried older ones)

logger dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-to-slf4j', version: '2.10.0'
```

(tried others (slf-log4j12) as well, without success)

log4j.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no other configuration placed somewhere, which might be overriding yours (in particular the debug log level)? The logo is logged with info level, but most other jOOQ logs are logged with debug or trace level.

Comment: You're probably right. Could not find it out though. As a solution implemented custom ExecuteListener where I do log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a result of conflicting dependencies.
If anyone stumbles upon this problem, as an alternative you can implement `ExecuteListener` as [shown here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/#N1255F) 
and call your log statements there.

Answer (score 0):

With this log4j2 configuration I have logged jooq queries:

```
<Configuration>
  ...
  <Loggers>
    ...
    <!-- This disables logging the jooq logo -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.jooq.Constants" level="warn"/>
    <!-- This enables logging queries -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.jooq" level="debug"/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```